# Is there a way to get user private and public key in hyperledger fabric for data encryption purposes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I recently started learning hyperledger fabric, I'm working on a simple private blockchain for managing digital data, this data would be encrypted with user public key and can only be decrypted with the user private key, so my question is, is there a way to get user private and public key in hyperledger fabric for data encryption purposes

Answer (score 0):

yes, fabric uses public-key infrastructure. Every transaction in the fabric is signed by the user's private key. And at chaincode level, you can get the public key of the user from its E-certs.

More about Identity from fabric docs
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/identity/identity.html

CID golang package to get E-cert at chaincode level https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/tree/master/pkg/cid

Comment: Hey, Pritam. I tried getting the keys manually myself from the wallet, which I think it's wrong, even though it works but I got to understand that the keys are not RSA because I was trying to use node-RSA to encrypt the data using the key I got from the user Wallet. but kekomal made a really nice point, I will try that out and give you guys feedback

Comment: Elliptic Curve is used, so you cannot use RSA . you check more about certs from this [site](https://certlogik.com/decoder/) copy/paste cert from signcert.

Answer (score 0):

Although MSP ECDSA keys are used to sign, you can use them to encrypt via ECDH. Basically you can derive the same shared secret from public key A and private key B as from public key B and private key A, so that you use that shared secret as a symmetric AES key to encrypt.

An example with `openssl`: https://jameshfisher.com/2017/04/14/openssl-ecc/. You don't need to create the key pairs as you already have them. You can implement it in javascript with `elliptic` and `crypto` libraries.

You manage your own private and public keys (in your client's wallet after enrolling), but you have to arrange your reliable way to distribute the other's public key. You can easily verify that public key if it is embedded in a valid certificate, but the way to distribute it is in your hand.

Comment: Thanks kekomal, i will try this out

Comment: You are welcome. Apart from ECDH, you have also ECIES encryption schema that depends only in the other's public key, but I have not tested it in nodejs with Fabric's P-256 curve.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134946/can-i-use-the-public-private-key-generated-by-the-msp-in-hyperledger-fabric-v1-0, I'm currently facing this issue too, I tried using `elliptic` library, I can't use node-RSA because it's not supported yet

Comment: That is why I have told you to use ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman) to encrypt. Your error is trying to use node-RSA with ECDSA keys, which I haven't told you. Use `elliptic` and `crypto`. And `jsrsasign` to "play" with your keys.

Comment: Read the identity from your wallet. Use `jsrsasign` to extract the keys from your identity, Use `elliptic`'s 'p256' curve to derive your shared secret and use `crypto` to encrypt with the derived shared secret.